# Rule CA1709 and two letter-words

Tags: code-analysis

I have a library with a lot of functions that use two letter-non english-words like this:

- FinDeDia
- EsPrimo
- EnPreparacion
- ...

Anyway, I activated code analysys for the project, and I'm getting the CA1709 warning:

```
CA1709 : Microsoft.Naming : 
Corrija el uso de mayúsculas y minúsculas en 'De' en el nombre del miembro '...' cambiándolo a 'DE'.
```

I added a code analysis dictionary as stated [here](http://www.markzhou.com/blog/post/Resource-string-compound-words-should-be-cased-correctly-%28CA1701-MicrosoftNaming%29.aspx) but it doesn't ignore the warnings. Here is the structure of the dictionary.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dictionary>
  <Words>
    <Recognized>
      <Word>de</Word>
      <Word>el</Word>
      <Word>en</Word>
      <Word>es</Word>
      <Word>si</Word>
      ...
    </Recognized>
  </Words>
</Dictionary>
```

What else should i do for handling this warning Without supressing the message?.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add them as `CasingExceptions` aswell:

```
  <Acronyms>
    <CasingExceptions>
      <Acronym>De</Acronym>
      <Acronym>El</Acronym>
      <Acronym>En</Acronym>
      <Acronym>Es</Acronym>
      <Acronym>Si</Acronym>
    </CasingExceptions>
  </Acronyms>
</Dictionary>
```

**EDIT:**
Just be aware of the fact that this is somewhat a misuse, since none of those words are acronyms. Maybe you'd rather want to disable those specific rules. Afterall, many of code analysis' rules are based on the assumption that the API is written in English.